# How to autofill a form field with random number using javascript in google chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, forms, random, google-chrome-extension

In the options of my chrome extension I'd like to autofill a form field when the options page is opened. I have some code for this in the option.js file but it doesn't seem to autofill on opening.

I've tried some code which I will attach.

```
(function() {
        var randomString = function(length) {

            var text = "";

            var possible = "0123456789";

            for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {

                text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

            }

            return text;
        }

        // random string length
        var random = randomString(10);

        // insert random string to the field
        var elem = document.getElementById("email").value = random;

    })();
```

I'm using the 'email' form field for the moment to test the code - I would create a new form field once the code works.

Comment: Enclose the entire (function{}()) in parentheses to make it an IIFE.

Comment: Hi, I've tried that and it still doesn't generate it

Comment: You can debug your options.js by right-clicking inside the options dialog and then clicking "inspect". It'll open devtools where you can set breakpoints in your code and inspect the variables, etc.

Comment: This is the error I currently get with the added parentheses: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
    at options.js:21
    at options.js:23"

Comment: @Arran - It mean your `html` do not have input element with id `email`.

Comment: I definitely have an element named "email" - it's one of the form fields - the html for it is: <input type="text" name="email" id="email".....

Comment: You probably have your `<script>` before that element. Either move the script before the closing `</body>` tag or use DOMContentLoaded listener.

Comment: at the moment that's the only code I have in options.js so that might be why - I'm still learning so I'm a bit unsure on how to do it. Do I set the listener within the function or before the function?

Comment: I got it to work!! Thank you both for your help! It is much appreciated

Comment: now onto capturing that number in storage